# What actually happens when i scale mysql or some nosql datasource horizontally?

Tags: mysql, nosql, memcached, scaling

If I scale the both MySQL or some NoSQL database horizontally, Will the data contains in each source replicated? Because in Memcache from what I know, it adds a new server but does not replicate the data that is already existed. Is it the same case in the matters of other databases as well?

Comment: MySQL doesnt scale horizontally. So nothing will happen. If the data was just replicated for scalable database systems, they would not be scalable. They would still be limited by the maximum size of a single node. So no, not all data is replicated. It is much, much more complicated than that! Also, memchace is not a database - clue's in the name...

Comment: Perhaps try reading this to get you started? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31651487/how-does-cassandra-scale-horizontally

Comment: Why MySQL can't be scaled horizontally?

Comment: Why can't cars fly? Because that's not what they're for. If you want to drive fast on a road, get a car. If you want to fly you'll need something else.